# Assistance with luggage at London Heathrow

Tags: luggage, lhr, services

I would like to know if a porter can take my suitcases from terminal 2 to terminal 3 at London Heathrow, to take them to left luggage until I fly out the next day, as I’d prefer not to take them to my hotel and back in the morning.

It is not a connecting flight, so I cannot check them through. I have four suitcases and am travelling alone.

Comment: Which airport do you use? Is this a transit overnight flight?

Comment: Opps Heathrow Airport . I arrive terminal 2 leave in the morning terminal 3. Not a connecting flight,, will stay in a hotel at the Airport , but don’t want the hassle of taking all my suitcases.

Answer (score 5):

There are both porter and left baggage service available at Heathrow.

I assume you need to reserve a porter for your arrival and departure to help you with your luggage.

https://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/terminal-facilities-and-services/porters

https://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/terminal-facilities-and-services/left-baggage

Comment: I find it amusing that unattended luggage (being a security risk) is often ignored.  I spent several minutes trying to guess who owned an item with no one anywhere near it.  Eventually, I would have reported it, if I hadn't seen security people walk past it without apparently noticing.  And I I wanted to set off a bomb in an airport, I could just pay five to ten dollars/pounds/euro to put it in consignment to guarantee security won't mess with it.

Comment: I think luggage left in consignment are scanned the same way they are when passing security.

Comment: Not the one I left.  Took my payment, tagged the bag, and set it next to others.  It could have been scanned after I was out of sight, but I doubt it.  "Security" in most places is not even as good as a placebo.